# Is there a system support for HUD-style window with a red close button?

Tags: macos, cocoa

I have stumbled upon this window style:

[image: window sample]

HUD-style black, translucent window body, no visual difference between the title bar and the window content, red closing button. Is this window style officially offered by the system? If so, what do I do to get it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get quite close with the following code:

```
[window setTitlebarAppearsTransparent:YES];
[[window standardWindowButton:NSWindowMiniaturizeButton] setHidden:YES];
[[window standardWindowButton:NSWindowZoomButton] setHidden:YES];
```

Plus `NSVisualEffectView` for the blurred background.